# How to Serialize with a Foreign Key in Django

Tags: django-rest-framework

I made serializers and views on my project , the route works when i don't add the others (in fact , they work one to one but not together).

i have AttributeError: module 'name.views' has no attribute 'name2_list'

i tried to nested but it doesn't work.

what could it be ?

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you.

Comment: as there is no codes shown, I guess you have used `uniqe=True` or `OneToOne` filed.

Comment: hello , finally i found the problem it was because i imported 4 views and django thought it was only one. Thanks for those answers

Comment: @Zxyao Can you please post the code which gave you this problem in your question, and you can answer your own question with the solution which should contribute to your reputation.